# Change icons in children after click button in parent - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a sortable list with topics and pages.
[image]

I want to do the follow thing: when I click in a eye button in a topic, the topic and your page children will be hide, changing their view icons. That is, if you change the icon on a topic, it changes for all your children.
For example:

[image]

Currently I can change the view icons in topic only. How do I do to change the view icon in pages children too?

PHP code:

```
//printing topic
    if($list[$i]->getObj()->getSTop_view() == 0){
        $view_icon = '<img id="imgEye" title="Hide" name="hide" src="/imgs/icons/ic_hide_16x16.png">';
    } else {
        $view_icon = '<img id="imgEye" title="Show" name="show" src="/imgs/icones/ic_show_16x16.png">';
    }

    $html.= '<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="'.$list[$i]->getObj()->getTop_id().'" view-value="'.$list[$i]->getObj()->getTop_view().'">
                    <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">'.$list[$i]->getObj()->getTop_name().'</div>
                    <div class="dd3-content">
                        <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;">'.$list[$i]->getObj()->getTop_name().'</span>
                        <span class="span-right">
                            <a id="UpdateViewTop" name="'.$list[$i]->getObj()->getTop_id().'">'.$view_icon.'</a>
                            <a class="edit-button" href="..."><img title="Edit" src="/imgs/icons/ic_edit_16x16.png"></a>
                            <a class="del-button"><img title="Delete" src="/imgs/icons/ic_delete_16x16.png"></a>
                        </span> 
                    </div>';

    for($j=($i+1);$j < $cont_int;$j++) { //if the topic have children
//printing pages
        if($list[$j]->getObj()->getPag_view() == 0) {
            $view_icon = '<img id="imgEye" title="Hide" name="hide"  src="/imgs/icons/ic_hide_16x16.png">';
        } else {
            $view_icon = '<img id="imgEye" title="Show" name="show" src="/imgs/icones/ic_show_16x16.png">';
        }

        $html.= '<ol id="stopitem" class="dd-list">
                     <li id="pagstopitem" class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="'.$list[$j]->getObj()->getPag_id().'" view-value="'.$list[$j]->getObj()->getPag_view().'">
                        <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle"></div>
                        <div class="dd3-content">
                            <span><a href="...">'.$list[$j]->getObj()->getPag_name().'</a></span>
                            <span class="span-right">
                                <a id="UpdateViewPag" name="'.$list[$j]->getObj()->getPag_id().'">'.$view_icon.'</a>
                                <a class="edit-button" href="..."><img title="Edit" src="/imgs/icons/ic_edit_16x16.png"></a>
                                <a class="delpagstop-button" name="'.$list[$j]->getObj()->getPag_id().'"><img title="Delete" src="/imgs/icons/ic_delete_16x16.png"></a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </li>';
    ...
    }
```

Javascript and Ajax code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#UpdateViewTop', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var uid = $(this).attr('name');
    var img = $(this).children('#imgEye');
    var eye = img.attr('name');

    var myData_IC_hide = '/imgs/icons/ic_hide_16x16.png';
    var myData_IC_show = '/imgs/icons/ic_show_16x16.png';


    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/control/ajax/view.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: uid},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function() {
            //here change the icon in topic when I click in eye button
            //that's works fine!
            //Now I want to change the icon in page children

            if(eye == "show") {

                img.attr('src', myData_IC_hide);
                img.attr('name', 'hide');
                img.attr('title', 'Hide');

            } else if(eye == "hide") {

                img.attr('src', myData_IC_show);
                img.attr('name', 'show');
                img.attr('title', 'Show');

            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Are you generating duplicate `id`? In that case, you won't get intended result. Hint: you might use jQuery `find` method to change image of children.

Comment: I tryied but not success. I put the follow code:  $(this).find("#stopitem > li > div > span > a > img").attr('src', myData_IC_hide);

Comment: `#stopitem` is not the child of `UpdateViewTop`, so you cannot use `$(this).find`. Just use `$('#stopitem > li > div > span > a > img').attr('src', myData_IC_hide);`.

Comment: @LwinHtooKo the problem is that change for all pages, even those belonging to another topic. I don't want this. I want to change for pages for certain topic.

Comment: I have many topics. Each one has pages children. When I click to hide one topic, only your children pages will hide and not all children pages.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you!
I add an id in each topic.